# Mapping letters in a string to number of occurences, using Stream

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

I've got a string `s`, and I'm trying to map each letter in `s` to the number of times it appears in `s`, using the Stream API.
For example, `giraffe -> {1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1}`.
The code I've tried using is:

```
String s = "giraffe";
int[] occurences = s.chars().map(c -> count(s, c)).toArray();

public int count(String text, char ch) {
    return (int) text.chars().filter(c -> c == ch).count();
}
```

but I get `incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to char` on the line that starts with `int[] occurences = ...`
I've tried some different variations but nothing has worked. Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The problem

The real cause of your problem is that there isn’t any `CharStream` class. For this reason `s.chars()` gives you an `IntStream`. For this reason in turn in `map(c -> count(s, c))`, `c` has type `int`. So you are trying to pass an `int` to your `count` method where it expects a `char`.  This gives you your error message. An `int` can be converted to a `char`, but some bits will be discarded, which is why the conversion is necessarily *lossy*.

### The two obvious solutions

**Solution 1:** Tell Java that you mean to make this lossy conversion. Since you know that `c` comes from a `char` from your string, converting it back to a `char` again won’t do any harm.

```
    int[] occurences = s.chars().map(c -> count(s, (char) c)).toArray();
```

**Solution 2:**

You may declare your method to accept an `int`:

```
public int count(String text, int ch) {
```

Now no conversion (cast) is needed. The comparison `c == ch` still works fine. It is comparing two `int`s anyway, so no harm is done.

PS There are other fine solutions and refinements in the other answers. Personally I’d be tempted to preprocess the string into a map of counts so I need not count again for each letter. This is not necessary, your code works fine with just one of the two changes mentioned.

Comment: Awesome, detailed answer. Thank you, I didn't realise the problem was due to `c` being converted to an int

Answer (score 1):

I have modified your `count` method to accept `int` instead of `char` and it works

```
import java.util.Arrays;
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    String s = "giraffe";
int[] occurences = s.chars().map(c -> count(s, c)).toArray();

 System.out.println(Arrays.toString(occurences));


  }
  public static int count(String text, int ch) {
    return (int) text.chars().filter(c -> c == ch).count();
}
}
```

See [repl](https://replit.com/join/ebwlgvcn-shubhamdixit863)

Answer (score 1):

Using loops, I would do it like this.

- allocate an array to hold all the characters
- then only print the ones that are non-zero

```
int[] count = new int[256]; // default to all 0's
for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
    count[c]++;  // use the character to index the array and update the count
}

for (int i = 0; i < count.size; i++) {
   if (count[i] > 0) {
      System.out.println((char)i + " " + count[i]);
    }
}
```

You can also use a stream to convert to a map. The order will be different but the frequency counts will be the same. It works as follows:

- split the string and stream the characters.
- group them by character
- and apply the counting collector when a key is found to update the count.

```
String s = "giraffe";
Map<String, Long> freq = Arrays.stream(s.split("")).collect(
        Collectors.groupingBy(c -> c, Collectors.counting()));

freq.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

prints

```
a=1
r=1
e=1
f=2
g=1
i=1
```

Answer (score 1):

There can be many ways to do it. One of the ways is to use `\X` as the regex which specifies [any Unicode extended grapheme cluster](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and group by the captured `Matcher` groups.

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.regex.MatchResult;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        Stream.of(
                    "giraffe", 
                    "Hello"
                ).forEach(s -> System.out.println(getFrequencyMap(s)));
    }

    static Map<Object, Long> getFrequencyMap(String s) {
        return Pattern.compile("\\X").matcher(s).results()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(MatchResult::group, LinkedHashMap::new, Collectors.counting()));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
{g=1, i=1, r=1, a=1, f=2, e=1}
{H=1, e=1, =1, l=2, o=1}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but I think `Streams` is NOT A GOOD for this. The easies way is to use `Map`:

```
public static Map<Character, Integer> histogram(String str) {
    Map<Character, Integer> map = new TreeMap<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        char ch = Character.toLowerCase(str.charAt(i));
        map.put(ch, map.getOrDefault(ch, 0) + 1);
    }

    return map;
}
```